# How to call a function programmatically in Python specifying a module programmatically also?

Tags: python, package

I can't use this

```
import foo
method_to_call = getattr(foo, 'bar')
result = method_to_call()
```

because module name is hardcoded and I can't use this

```
module = __import__('foo')
func = getattr(module, 'bar')
func()
```

because module is nested.

I tried this

```
customer = 'jci'
module = __import__('customer.{customer_name}.gt'.format(customer_name=customer_name)) # AttributeError: module 'customer' has no attribute 'get_gt'
#module = __import__('customer.{customer_name}'.format(customer_name=customer_name), fromlist=['gt']) # AttributeError: module 'customer.jci' has no attribute 'get_gt'
#module = __import__('customer.{customer_name}.gt'.format(customer_name=customer_name), fromlist=[]) # AttributeError: module 'customer' has no attribute 'get_gt'
func = getattr(module, 'get_gt')
gt = func()
```

but failed with errors, specified in comment along with each variant.

`get_gt()` is a function inside `gt.py` file inside `customer/jci` directory. Each directory has empty `__init__.py` inside.

The following hardcoded code works:

```
import customer.jci.gt as g
gt = g.get_gt()
```

How to overcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

---

Note that `__import__` *does* handle dotted names but it returns the *parent* package, not the last child.

Proof:

```
>>> http = __import__('http.client')
>>> http.client   # the client submodule was imported
<module 'http.client' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py'>
>>> # without specifying the .client in the name the submodule is not imported
>>> __import__('http').client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'
```

`import_module` instead returns the child module, which is what most people expect:

```
>>> importlib.import_module('http.client')
<module 'http.client' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py'>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, anyway if his package has a class and he wants the method from class, he will return to initial case.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I don't understand what you are saying. There is no one function where you can specify `package.module.class.method` and get a reference to the method. The OP already knows how to retriever an attribute using `getattr`, the only issue they had is the one I explained in the answer.

Comment: You're right @Bakuriu, I have misunderstood the question. Sorry :-(